# Is there any easy way to convert a standard SQL statement into a dynamic query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, execute

I have a pretty complex SQL query that is pulling data from a our database for a particular month `@month`.

The month is based on our internal month-numbering system, so at the beginning of the code, we define the month number we would like to use.

I have now been informed that we need this code running for the previous 12 months, is there an easy way to convert the whole code into an `EXEC` statement so I can `loop` through the different values of the `@month` variable?

I've done this before for simple code, but this one has lots of string-based criteria, which would need to be manually edited to accommodate all the inverted commas (').

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of converting your code to dynamic SQL and run it in a loop, it would probably be better to convert it to be able to handle a set of months instead of a single month. Since you didn't share any code, though, I can't help with any tips for this.

Comment: Please provide us with your current code, then we'll convert it to dynamic...

Answer (score 0):

Put your query inside a store procedure with @month param in input, then call you procedure 12 time:

```
s_procName 1
s_procName 2
s_procName 3
.....
```